# Can I swap a SATA drive with one firmware type with one with another firmware type?

Tags: hard-drive, firmware

I hope this is pretty straight forward, but assume I have a Dell optiplex 780 (don't judge me) running Windows 7 SP1 with a Seagate 500GB 7200RPM SATA drive which lists Firmware: CC45. The hard drive dies (suprise) and I need to replace it with a Western Digital 1TB 7200RPM SATA drive which uses Firmware A0.

This should work right? Will there be a performance difference? I believe Dell uses A0 through A15 firmware for its BIOS so it shouldn't be a problem. Am I just being stupid? Sorry if I should post this elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: When would I typically have to worry about a HDD's firmware then?

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference in your situation. You shouldn't worry.